# Finding bluetooth with python script

Tags: python, bluetooth

I used this code and similiar things to this code. Every time i can only find 1 device and that device is like TV router and cant find my mobile and other bluetooths around me. I am sure that they are turned on and discoverable.

```
import bluetooth
for d in bluetooth.discover_devices(flush_cache=True):
    print d
```

Comment: Sorry for bad format of code

Comment: you might want to have a look at `pyBluez`. I couldn't find much about `bluetooth` in python.

Comment: pyBluez yea...this little script is pybluez i think

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. Please, give some more detail, what did you try and your research...